# App Unity/Vuforia Crash After Launch/Is Slow

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have an augmented reality application, I'm using **Unity 3D version 5.3.3f1**. The version of **vuforia is 6.2.10.**

The problems are as follows:

- Closes when application starts
- Sometimes when charging, it closes after a time of use.

These problems are presented more in old phones (mid-range 2 years ago or so), newer phones support the app better.

For whatever tests have been made the source of the problem are the 3D models (fbx format) which are in the Unity scene, placed on their respective targets, since the heavier the fbx file or the more models there are on the scene it is more likely that the application will close or be encouraged.

For now the size of each 3D model has been reduced making them simpler and has made the app work with more models than before, however there are still devices that can not support it.

Is there any way to reduce the size of fbx files, or any settings that allow better application performance?

Comment: Run the app plugged to Android studio or xcode so you can see the debug. It will print the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also faced the long delays on AR scene launch. I was using the same approach as you are. What I did to improve the performance was, loading the image targets without models (didn't set the models on image targets) and attached them to the respective image target dynamically on target detection.

Hope this helps.